# CSS3 Transitions, Keyframes, Animations

Tags: css, css-transitions, css-animations

I have been playing around with transitions and animations, and I wanted to make the most of using hover with them.

I was wondering if it is possible to make animation happen after being hovered over, not necessarily while hovering over it. For example, if I wanted a picture to slide in and change opacity after the related paragraph is hovered, how would I get it to stay without keeping the mouse of the section?

My last question is if something similar to keyframes can be used with transitions. I prefer transitions because they transition back to the original state instead of snapping back.

I made a jsfiddle with some basic code examples, and I am wondering how to expand upon them. Hopefully the examples help clarify what I am trying to explain.

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1771gmra/#&togetherjs=7fq6NSMlVy)

```
Says I need code to link jsfiddle
```

They are very simple, the first is just an animation (left to right) that I want to remain after hovering once.

The second is a transition (left to right), and I am wondering if I can make an animation similar to the animation that follows it (left to right to left)

Comment: *Says I need code to link jsfiddle* - That means you need to post code and not format text as code :) Coming to the question, a combination of animation and transition doesn't work in WebKit browsers (and even in FF it has some problems). You can find some information about the reason in this answer - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32142484/combination-of-animation-and-transition-not-working-properly/32142949#32142949.

Comment: If I cannot combine the two, is there a way to make animations return to the original state without just "bouncing" back? I skimmed what you linked, but I do not want to use jquery or javascript.

Answer (score 0):

I update the fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/1771gmra/2/)

However, "left to right to left" can not accomplish through transition.
Because transition only has start status and end status, it can not handle the middle status. 
Look here. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transition

You can accomplish "left to right to left" through keyframes. For example.

```
    @keyframes slideRight {
     0% {
        margin-left: 0em;
      }
      50% {
        margin-left: 2em;
      }
      100% {
        margin-left: 0em
       }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the SlideRight code. I did not seem to update my fiddle correctly as I thought I posted something similar. Do you know if it is possible to make the hover state remain?

Comment: Just don't write animation style in :hover status, but another classname, such as animation-hover. When you mouseEnter the div, add the classname 'animation-hover' to it .That's it.

Comment: Does this mean it is impossible to have the effect persist after being hovered over without using JavaScript?