# How can I jump to another stage of my animation on CSS keyframes?

Tags: css, animation, css-animations

I just wanna jump to another stage of my animation.. ex: after the 100% animation jump to 25% instead 0%..

```
@keyframes animation {
  0% { /*animation 1*/ }
  25% { /*animation 2*/ }
  50% { /*animation 3*/ }
  75% { /*animation 4*/ }
  100% { /*animation 5 // and jump to 25% instead 0%*/ }
}
```

EDIT1: Here is a very simple example.. the first stage is WHITE, but after I wanna keep it swapping in RED and GREEN..

EDIT2: Guys, I solved it using two different animations, as u can see bellow, thx for the answers! :D

```css
        .test {
          display:block;
          width:50px;
          height:50px;
          animation: animatedBg 4s, animatedBg2 2s infinite 2s alternate;
        }

        @keyframes animatedBg {
          0% {
            background: white;
          }
            100% {
            background: red;
          }
        }

        @keyframes animatedBg2 {
          0% {
            background: red;
          }
            100% {
            background: green;
          }
        }
```

```html
<div class="test"></div>
```

Comment: You mean the next iteration needs to start at 20% keyframe? That's not possible.

Comment: Actually 25%! Sorry.

Comment: I'm swapping two background images, but in the first keyframe (0%) both of these images are in opacity 0, so I need jump to the second keyframe to get these two images swapping..
ps. sorry abt my poor english D:

Comment: Please create a demo so that we can see if there is any alternate way to achieve this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **Note:** Don't change the background image itself within keyframes as it is not supposed to work (and won't work) in FF, IE. You can find more info in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35994521/background-image-in-keyframe-does-not-display-in-firefox-or-internet-explorer/36005661#36005661). If you are only swapping opacity then it is fine.

As far as I know there is no way to achieve the effect that you are looking for with only one animation. Instead you could have a look at using a combination of two animations like in the below snippet. Here the first animation fades color from white to green over 2.5s (= 50% of 5s) and this animation runs only one time (iteration count = 1). The second animation fades color from green to red over 2.5s. This one has a delay of 2.5s because it has to be idle while the first animation is running and then it executes in an infinite loop (iteration count = infinite). This produces the effect that you are looking for.

```css
.test {
  display: block;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  animation: animatedBg1 2.5s 1, /* 2.5s because it was 50% and only 1 iteration for white to green */
             animatedBg 2.5s 2.5s infinite; /* wait 2.5s then infinitely loop the green to red */
}
@keyframes animatedBg1 {
  0% {
    background: white;
  }
  100% {
    background: green;
  }
}
@keyframes animatedBg {
  0% {
    background: green;
  }
  100% {
    background: red;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="test"><div>
```

---

Similarly below is a sample for your original animation. Here, I am assuming the `animation-duration` to be 5s, so the 25% keyframe will happen at 1.25s and thus the `animation-duration` for first one will be 1.25s. The second animation's duration will be the remaining 3.75s. Now since one frame is moved to a separate animation of its own (and duration has changed), the other keyframe percentages in the second animation will have to be different from the original one. For example, in your original animation the 50% keyframe would have happened at 2.5s and so in a two animation approach, it should happen at 1.25s of 2<sup>nd</sup> animation. 1.25s would mean ***a third*** of the 2<sup>nd</sup> animation's duration, so the percentage would 33%. Similarly the 75% keyframe in original animation would happen at 3.75s duration. It means that this should happen at 2.5s of the second animation which is nothing but ***two thirds*** of the second animation and thus gets 66% keyframe.

```css
.test {
  display: block;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  animation: animatedBg1 1.25s 1, animatedBg 3.75s 1.25s infinite;
}
@keyframes animatedBg1 {
  0% {
    background: white;
  }
  100% {
    /* this should be the 25% keyframe */
    background: green;
  }
}
@keyframes animatedBg {
  0% {
    /* same as 25% keyframe */
    background: green;
  }
  33% {
    /* same as 50% keyframe, percentage different as duration has changed and we have moved one keyframe to a different animation */
    background: tomato;
  }
  66% {
    background: rebeccapurple;
  }
  100% {
    background: red;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="test">
  <div>
```

Comment: Yeah, I know, but this job is not for browsers but for an ipad app :D

Comment: @RailtonSantos Ok but the approach should still work. Have you tried it? Does it give you any errors or problems? If yes, let me know and I'll see how that can be addressed.

Comment: Thanks Harry, I already solved it, as u can see up there.. (:

Comment: @RailtonSantos: Isn't that method the same as my answer? I don't know but if you think my answer was useful for you, you can mark it as the solution by clicking the hollow/empty tick mark below the voting buttons next to this answer. That is generally how problems are marked as "solved" in SO. Alternately, if none of the answers satisfied you and you have a completely new method then you could post your own solution as an answer and accept it. Please do not edit and add the solution into the question. That is not how it is meant to be in SO :)

Comment: yes, your answer and the OP edit are basically the same :-)

Comment: yeah, sorry for that, it's my first time asking here, thx guys :D

Answer (score 2):

You can combine `animation` and `transition` effects, set `animation-delay` that would be equal transition duration and start animation from final settings of transition.

Here is an example:

```css
.cont {
    height: 200px;
    background: #ccf;
}
.blk {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: #fc9;
    transition: all 2s ease;   
}
.cont:hover .blk {
    left: 200px;
    animation: anim 2s infinite; 
    animation-delay: 2s;
}

@keyframes anim {
    0% {
        left: 200px;
    }
    100% {
        left: 200px;
        top: 100px;
    }
    
}
```

```html
<div class="cont">
<div class="blk">test</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Just a word of caution - Animations and Transitions don't always work well together cross browser. Here is one such case - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32142484/combination-of-animation-and-transition-not-working-properly/32142949#32142949

Comment: @Harry Even though you are right, this particular use case shouldn't have any problem. (using first a transition and later a delayed animation, and no fill-mode )

Comment: Yes indeed @vals I definitely do agree with your point. This particular use case at present will not have a problem but what I was trying to say is that usage of transition + animation on the same property (at the same state) is a bit of a grey area. It isn't fully defined as to which one should take control and so we never know if the browser could break something tomorrow. That's why I just said that it is a word of caution (as in, keep in mind that something *can* go wrong).

Comment: Another thing (sorry again, I have no intention of degrading Banzay's good answer but just pointing out), we don't know if the animation runs on user interaction. If it doesn't then using transitions might not be an option.