# How to force @keyframes play till of its end after on mouseout?

Tags: javascript, css, animation, css-animations

I have a keyframe animation which plays when I hover on element. After the `mouseout` event, it stops too abruptly. How could I force it play till it's end? I tried `on.(animationend)` event, it doesn't work. Transform origin and huge delay, either don't work. Thanks.

[CodePen Demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jBWrYR)

```js
class Main {
  constructor() {

  }


  waveOn() {
    $(this).addClass('wave-active');
  }

  waveOut() {
    var elem = $('.info__block');

    elem.removeClass('wave-active');
  }

  jsInit() {
    $('.info__block').hover(this.waveOn);
    $('.info__block').on('animationend', this.waveOut)
  }

}

new Main().jsInit();
```

```css
.info__block {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: aqua;
  border-radius: 50px;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-top: 100px;
}

.info__block:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 50px;
  border-top: 2px solid aqua;
}

.info__block.wave-active:before {
  animation: link-line 2.5s infinite .5s linear;
}

@keyframes link-line {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(0);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  60% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateY(-50%) scale(1.6);
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="info__block info__block-1">
</div>
```

Comment: Looks like a dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31806649/how-to-run-the-css3-animation-to-the-end-if-the-selector-is-not-matching-anymore/31833533#31833533. For your case, you should basically forget about the `:hover` selector. Use JS to trigger the animation on `mouseover` and then allow it to run till the end irrespective of whether the mouse is over the element or not.

Comment: Ok, I've found the problem. (a) Your CodePen CSS doesn't use the `.wave-active` class, it uses `:hover` and (b) An `infinite` animation has no `animationend`.

Comment: in different browser with diff css attribute for animation.e.g: IE @keyframes , firefox @-moz-keyframes.you must provide all for the browsers

Comment: Harry, thank you. The fact that infinite doesn't have animationend solved the problem!

Comment: @Alex: Did that answer based on `animationiteration` not help you? Is that not close to what you were looking for?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution to your problem using the native [`animationiteration` event](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-animations/#animationevent) that is described in the W3C Spec for animations. This event is fired after every single iteration of the animation. So, what we are doing is that on hover out, we are attaching the `animationiteration` event listener (which will get fired only once due to the `one`). Within this event's listener, I've simply placed the contents of original `waveOut` function. So, everytime you hover the mouse out of the element, the animation will complete one single iteration (after the hover out has happened) and then stop with that. I think this is a lot more graceful than an abrupt end.

```js
class Main {
  constructor() {}
  jsInit() {
    $('.info__block').hover(function() {
      $('.info__block').off('animationiteration'); /* switch off the event handler when you quickly hover back in again */
      $('.info__block').addClass('wave-active');
    }, function() {
      $('.info__block').one('animationiteration', function() {
        $('.info__block').removeClass('wave-active');
      })
    });
  }
}

new Main().jsInit();
```

```css
body {
  padding: 200px 200px;
}

.info__block {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: aqua;
  border-radius: 50px;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.info__block:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 50px;
  border-top: 2px solid aqua;
}

.info__block.wave-active:before {
  animation: link-line 2.5s infinite .5s linear;
}

@keyframes link-line {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(0);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  60% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateY(-50%) scale(1.6);
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="info__block info__block-1">
</div>
```

<strike>(*Note: In the above demo sometimes the animation stops after just one iteration during the second and subsequent hover operations. This seems to be some glitch with the Run Snippet window. I don't see this problem happening in the Editor's output window or in [**this CodePen demo**](http://codepen.io/hari_shanx/pen/JWGWXO). If you also encounter the same problem let me know and I'll see if there is any fix for it.*)</strike>

***Note:*** The problem mentioned above has been fixed and the snippet is also updated with the revised code. [Revised CodePen Demo](http://codepen.io/hari_shanx/pen/JWGWXO).

Answer (score 0):

An infinite animation doesn't have animationend event.