# Extend the final state of the first animation for translated element

Tags: css, css-animations, css-transforms

I know this is asked multiple times here, but I am asking for a different approach for these kind of animations.

**Problem:**

The 2nd box has multiple animations, trying to create the same effect as 1st one. It seems like the transform property is getting overwritten *(as it should)**. I am trying to extend the 1st animation (of 2nd box) with the properties of 2nd animation. Tried to use `animation-fill-mode: forwards` but with no success. Maybe I am missing something basic. Is it possible with vanilla CSS?

*[**Reference**](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-animations/#animation-name-property)

> The ‘animation-name’ property defines a list of animations that apply.
>   If multiple animations are
>   attempting to modify the same property, then the animation closest to
>   the end of the list of names wins.

---

**Requirement:**

Separate `move2-right` and `move2-down` key-frames rules but work on the same element, preserving the 1st animation transformation. If there is an alternate approach to this kind of animation, please guide me through it.

---

**Current output:**

```css
.animation-1,
.animation-2 {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  display: inline-block;
  background: white;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14), 0 3px 1px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 1px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
}
.movable-1,
.movable-2 {
  background: #41A186;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14), 0 3px 1px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 1px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: 50px;
}
.movable-1 {
  -webkit-animation-name: move1;
  animation-name: move1;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 4s;
  animation-duration: 4s;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0s;
  animation-delay: 0s;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
.movable-2 {
  -webkit-animation-name: move2-right, move2-down;
  animation-name: move2-right, move2-down;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 2s, 2s;
  animation-duration: 2s, 2s;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 4s, 6s;
  animation-delay: 4s, 6s;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards, forwards;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards, forwards;
}
@-webkit-keyframes move1 {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(0px);
    transform: translateX(0px);
  }
  50% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(30px);
    transform: translateX(30px);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(30px) translateY(50px);
    transform: translateX(30px) translateY(50px);
  }
}
@keyframes move1 {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(0px);
    transform: translateX(0px);
  }
  50% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(30px);
    transform: translateX(30px);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(30px) translateY(50px);
    transform: translateX(30px) translateY(50px);
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes move2-right {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(0px);
    transform: translateX(0px);
  }
  50% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(30px);
    transform: translateX(30px);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(30px);
    transform: translateX(30px);
  }
}
@keyframes move2-right {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(0px);
    transform: translateX(0px);
  }
  50% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(30px);
    transform: translateX(30px);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(30px);
    transform: translateX(30px);
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes move2-down {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0px);
    transform: translateY(0px);
  }
  50% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(50px);
    transform: translateY(50px);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(50px);
    transform: translateY(50px);
  }
}
@keyframes move2-down {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0px);
    transform: translateY(0px);
  }
  50% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(50px);
    transform: translateY(50px);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(50px);
    transform: translateY(50px);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="animation-1">
  <div class="movable-1">1</div>
</div>
<div class="animation-2">
  <div class="movable-2">2</div>
</div>
```

Here is a fiddle you can play with: [**JSfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Manojkr/0z2ehwhd/1/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I am aware this is not possible with pure CSS because (as you have already indicated), when we add an extra transformation rule to an element which already has a transform, the whole transform gets reset because it overwrites and does not append to the existing transform.

With JS this might be possible to achieve but even there it is going to be tough because we have to do the following:

- Handle the `animationend` event on completion of the first animation.
- In the handler, get the `translateX(...)` in pixels.
- Get the CSS keyframe rules of the next animation, modify them to take the `translateX(...)` as the first part of the transform stack.

**Note:** I assume that you have a case where there is absolutely no way for you to use the first method mentioned in the question.

---

An alternate method to achieve a similar effect would be to animate the `margin` or `position` of an element instead of using `transform: translate()`. One major downside to this approach is that this would not done at the GPU layer (unlike `transform`) and hence would be slower when multiple such animations happen at the same time (and could also be expensive).

**Using Margins:**

The below snippet achieves the effect by animating `margin-left` and `margin-top` properties.

```css
.animation-1,
.animation-2,
.animation-3 {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  display: inline-block;
  background: white;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14), 0 3px 1px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 1px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.movable-1,
.movable-2,
.movable-3 {
  background: #41A186;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14), 0 3px 1px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 1px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: 50px;
}
.movable-1 {
  animation-name: move1;
  animation-duration: 4s;
  animation-delay: 0s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
.movable-2 {
  animation-name: move2-right, move2-down;
  animation-duration: 2s, 2s;
  animation-delay: 4s, 6s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards, forwards;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
}
.movable-3 {
  animation-name: move3-diagonal;
  animation-duration: 4s;
  animation-delay: 8s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
}
@keyframes move1 {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(0px);
  }
  50% {
    transform: translateX(30px);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(30px) translateY(50px);
  }
}
@keyframes move2-right {
  0% {
    margin-left: 0px;
  }
  100% {
    margin-left: 30px;
  }
}
@keyframes move2-down {
  0% {
    margin-top: 0px;
  }
  100% {
    margin-top: 50px;
  }
}
@keyframes move3-diagonal
 {
  0% {
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-left: 0px;
  }
  100% {
    margin-top: 50px;
    margin-left: 30px;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prefixfree/1.0.7/prefixfree.min.js"></script>
<div class="animation-1">
  <div class="movable-1">1</div>
</div>
<div class="animation-2">
  <div class="movable-2">2</div>
</div>
<div class="animation-3">
  <div class="movable-3">3</div>
</div>
```

---

**Using Position:**

This snippet achieves the same effect by animation `left` and `top` properties. The child element has `position: absolute`.

```css
.animation-1,
.animation-2,
.animation-3 {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  display: inline-block;
  background: white;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14), 0 3px 1px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 1px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
  position: relative;
}
.movable-1,
.movable-2,
.movable-3 {
  background: #41A186;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14), 0 3px 1px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 1px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
}
.movable-1 {
  animation-name: move1;
  animation-duration: 4s;
  animation-delay: 0s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
.movable-2 {
  animation-name: move2-right, move2-down;
  animation-duration: 2s, 2s;
  animation-delay: 4s, 6s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards, forwards;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
}
.movable-3 {
  animation-name: move3-diagonal;
  animation-duration: 4s;
  animation-delay: 8s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
}
@keyframes move1 {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(0px);
  }
  50% {
    transform: translateX(30px);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(30px) translateY(50px);
  }
}
@keyframes move2-right {
  0% {
    left: 0px;
  }
  100% {
    left: 30px;
  }
}
@keyframes move2-down {
  0% {
    top: 0px;
  }
  100% {
    top: 50px;
  }
}
@keyframes move3-diagonal {
  0% {
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
  }
  100% {
    top: 50px;
    left: 30px;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prefixfree/1.0.7/prefixfree.min.js"></script>
<div class="animation-1">
  <div class="movable-1">1</div>
</div>
<div class="animation-2">
  <div class="movable-2">2</div>
</div>
<div class="animation-3">
  <div class="movable-3">3</div>
</div>
```

---

**Note:** As described in my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34411082/animate-transform-only-one-property-scale-override-other-translate-css3/34412049#34412049), you can of-course add a wrapper element and set the move-down animation to it. This would produce the same effect as the first one but I am not suggesting that approach because it is against the very point of your question (which in my opinion was - *how to add multiple animations to the same element and make the second start from where the first ended*).

```css
.animation-1,
.animation-2 {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  display: inline-block;
  background: white;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14), 0 3px 1px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 1px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
}
.movable-1,
.movable-2 {
  background: #41A186;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14), 0 3px 1px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 1px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: 50px;
}
.movable-1 {
  animation-name: move1;
  animation-duration: 4s;
  animation-delay: 0s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
.movable-2 {
  animation-name: move2-right;
  animation-duration: 2s;
  animation-delay: 4s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
.movable-2-wrapper {
  animation-name: move2-down;
  animation-duration: 2s;
  animation-delay: 6s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
@keyframes move1 {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(0px);
  }
  50% {
    transform: translateX(30px);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(30px) translateY(50px);
  }
}
@keyframes move2-right {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(0px);
  }
  50% {
    transform: translateX(30px);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(30px);
  }
}
@keyframes move2-down {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(0px);
  }
  50% {
    transform: translateY(50px);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateY(50px);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prefixfree/1.0.7/prefixfree.min.js"></script>
<div class="animation-1">
  <div class="movable-1">1</div>
</div>
<div class="animation-2">
  <div class='movable-2-wrapper'>
    <div class="movable-2">2</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Accepting this answer. I was going to create the code for further translation types(Diagonal). Since diagonal transition can be produced using translate(x,y), I wanted all the transitions to be linear. Never mind I will choose the position method.

Comment: Oh I see. In that case you can change both margins (or both positions) inside a single keyframe and it will do diagonal motion. Wait, I will add a sample :)

Comment: That's nice. I will just choose the position method. Any drawbacks of it instead of translate() ?

Comment: @ManojKumar: Nope, I don't see any drawback other than the Graphic Layer (GPU) thing that I mentioned earlier.

Comment: @ManojKumar: Not sure if this helps but adding a wrapper like I mentioned [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34411082/animate-transform-only-one-property-scale-override-other-translate-css3/34412049#34412049) would work if it is just 2 animations per element. Anything more and it'd become messy.

Comment: That is a very nice approach, Harry. Thanks a lot for your time on my question :)