# How to set 0% css of keyframes as current css value for the element?

Tags: javascript, css, html, css-animations

I am trying to make a progress indicator div using CSS animations. Please refer to the linked JSBin. The behavior I am trying to achieve is, when the user clicks on stage3 after stage1, the div width should increase from current 30% to 100% and not start from 0% as it is doing right now. I know if i set the 0% value as width: 30%, I can get that. But it won't work so well if I have many stages. I want the animation to start from final width of last stage to the width specified in new stage.

[Progress indicator snippet](https://jsbin.com/buhozivuyi/edit?html,css,output)

```js
document.getElementById('stage1').addEventListener('click', function() {
  document.getElementById('progress').classList.add('stage1');
}, false);

document.getElementById('stage2').addEventListener('click', function() {
  document.getElementById('progress').classList.add('stage2');
}, false);

document.getElementById('stage3').addEventListener('click', function() {
  document.getElementById('progress').classList.add('stage3');
}, false);
```

```css
.progress-wrapper {
  height: 10px;
  width: 400px;
  background-color: #BBDEFB;
}
#progress {
  background-color: #AADE00;
  height: 10px;
  width: 0;
}
.stage1 {
  animation-name: stage1;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
@keyframes stage1 {
  to {
    width: 30%;
  }
}
.stage2 {
  animation-name: stage2;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
@keyframes stage2 {
  to {
    width: 70%;
  }
}
.stage3 {
  animation-name: stage3;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
@keyframes stage3 {
  to {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="progress-wrapper">
    <div id="progress"></div>
  </div>
  <pre>
    
  </pre>
  <button id="stage1">stage1</button>
  <button id="stage2">stage2</button>
  <button id="stage3">stage3</button>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: When there are multiple animations involved using same properties, CSS will use the latest and override the last. This is almost similar to this behavior: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32224802/extend-the-final-state-of-the-first-animation-for-translated-element

Comment: @ManojKumar Thank you. I will have to think of a different approach, there are just way too many combinations of starting value and final value for width.

Comment: Yes, I would suggest you to use Greensock Tweenmax/Timelinemax library. It is easy and fits your requirement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not aware of a CSS-only solution, but you could set the `width` of the `progress` element before adding the class.

In doing so, it will transition from the previous width rather than from `0`.

```js
var progress = document.getElementById('progress');

document.getElementById('stage1').addEventListener('click', function() {
  setPreviousWidth();
  progress.classList.add('stage1');
}, false);

document.getElementById('stage2').addEventListener('click', function() {
  setPreviousWidth();
  progress.classList.add('stage2');
}, false);

document.getElementById('stage3').addEventListener('click', function() {
  setPreviousWidth();
  progress.classList.add('stage3');
}, false);

function setPreviousWidth () {
  progress.style.width = progress.offsetWidth + 'px';
}
```

```css
.progress-wrapper {
  height: 10px;
  width: 400px;
  background-color: #BBDEFB;
}
#progress {
  background-color: #AADE00;
  height: 10px;
  width: 0;
}
.stage1 {
  animation-name: stage1;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
@keyframes stage1 {
  to {
    width: 30%;
  }
}
.stage2 {
  animation-name: stage2;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
@keyframes stage2 {
  to {
    width: 70%;
  }
}
.stage3 {
  animation-name: stage3;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
@keyframes stage3 {
  to {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="progress-wrapper">
  <div id="progress"></div>
</div>
<pre>
    
  </pre>
<button id="stage1">stage1</button>
<button id="stage2">stage2</button>
<button id="stage3">stage3</button>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, such a small tweak did it. Nice solution.

Answer (score 0):

you can use custom CSS variable:

1. create custom variable in css e.g

```css
element{ --temp_variable: 0; }
```

2. get current property value in JavaScript and assign to custom variable e.g. if you need color value of element <p> :

```js
element = querySelector("p");  //or any other selector
computed_element = getComputedStyle(element);
current_color = computed_element.getPropertyValue("color")
computed_element.setProperty("--temp_variable",current_color);
```

2. use that variable in CSS keyframe e.g.

```css
@keyframe{
0%{ color: var(--temp_variable) }
100% { ..... }
}
```