# Skew effect dissapears when applying an animation

Tags: javascript, css, css-transforms

I have applied a transform: -webkit-transform: skewY(170deg) on an element.
Its working fine.
Afterwards, i add to the skewed element a class that animates a scaleOut.
This is the animation:

```
.partialScaleOutAnimation{
    -webkit-animation: partialScaleOut 0.5s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes partialScaleOut {
    0%{
        -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    }

    100%{
        -webkit-transform: scale(0.3);
    }
}
```

for some reason when applying the animation, the skewed effect disappears. Why?

Comment: When you need multiple transforms on an element, they should be provided as space separated in the same property. Within the animation, there is only a scale transform and so the other disappears.

Comment: I know that. the issue is that i add the transformations in different times

Comment: Well, my first statement has your solution. You must concatenate any new transform that is added at a later time to the existing transform. There is **no alternate** (unless you want to add extra wrapper elements, apply one transform to the wrapper).

Comment: Have a look at these [1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30010523/add-a-transform-value-to-the-current-transforms-that-are-already-on-the-element/30010571#30010571), [2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34411082/animate-transform-only-one-property-scale-override-other-translate/34412049#34412049), [3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32224802/extend-the-final-state-of-the-first-animation-for-translated-element?lq=1).

Comment: @Harry You've done your homework, nice.